# Access Collections from outside Edge Chromium browser (Linux)

Tags: linux, onedrive, microsoft-edge

There is a very neat Collections feature in Edge Beta (Chromium based) as described in [Windows blog](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2019/12/09/improvements-collections-sync-microsoft-edge/) (first announced in May 2019) and more improved on March 2020 ([venturebeat blog](https://venturebeat.com/2020/03/30/microsofts-chromium-edge-is-getting-vertical-tabs-smart-copy-and-password-monitor/)). Collections are described as a “cloud-powered intelligence” to collect, organize, share, and export content you find while browsing.

Is it possible to access Collections for example outside the mentioned browser? If I understand the concept well, OneDrive storage is used for that, but I cannot find a proof of that neither in OneDrive itself (file structure) nor in the internet.
I am asking this question, because I would like to access Collection in **Linux** environment and I prefer straight way (ie. not "WINE + Edge Beta" overkill).

EDIT: I found, that you can export one whole Collection as a Word or Excel file and save it in OneDrive folder, however this feature is not backwards compatible (editing excel file does not edit Collection item - which is obvious of course).

Comment: if Edge for Linux is released ( https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/11/its-official-microsoft-edge-is-coming-to-linux ) it can solve my issue.

Comment: Microsoft Edge has not yet been released on Linux.  Even when it is released there is not guarantee that every one of it's feature will be support on Linux.  I wouldn't consider an answer that stated this was the case to be helpful to the community.  If you are unable to modify the Collections on Windows outside of the browser then it's unlikely this functionality exists on Linux.

Comment: so Edge for Linux released, but there is no support for logging in, thus not usable yet for me. You were very right @Ramhound, I may have to ask on microsoft community because it seems I have to access it from outside the browser.

Comment: Edge on Linux is only on the Dev channel which is basically Alpha/Beta state

Comment: Just to make it complete I posted an unanswered question to Microsoft community https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/msedge_other-msedge_macos/access-collections-feature-from-outside-edge/9621c47b-fa2d-4ae0-8504-616e939521cc

Comment: My comment was a year ago. Edge on Linux is in the same state it was, Microsoft announced a unified development cycle for all operating systems for edge recently

Answer (score 0):

I spent significant amount of time to reply on this:

It is NOT possible to access MS Edge collections from outside the browser itself and it seems MS is even not planning to do so (without an evidence).

It does not deserve any more words that this.

Comment: How do you know MS is not planning this, do you have a reference?

Comment: I wrote `without an evidence` quite clearly, however if you really need more words, feel free to visit: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/msedge_other-msedge_macos/access-edge-collections-from-outside-edge-browser/987582c7-fb68-4bc2-ac60-a107156183b7

Answer (score 0):

You *can* access your Collections from outside of the Edge browser!

1. Log into your Microsoft account where you are trying to access them.
2. Access https://www.bing.com/saves?FORM=SVSHRD

If your collections don't show up, you can try the following:

1. Check if your collections are being correctly sycned to your Microsoft Account. Ensure you're logged into your Microsoft Account within Edge. Go to Settings > Profiles > Sync and ensure all are turned on. Open Collections (Ctrl + Shift + Y) and interact with them, this could trigger a sync.
2. To additionally check, you can install the Edge browser on mobile, log in and see if your collections are showing up.

If your collections are being synced, you should be able to see them on Bing saves. [How bing.com/saves looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03KJb.png)

I want to point out that after wanting this feature myself, and not finding a single way online to do it, I accidentally discovered this feature. There is no documentation about this from Microsoft, but it *works*.

Edit: You can also access them through this link: https://edgeservices.bing.com/saves

Comment: I am not sure about that. I logged in to bing.com (with Microsoft account), opened the address and I cannot see any previously saved collections. Almost seems to me as a duplicate feature (which is even more confusing but typical for Microsoft). Anyway thank you for informing me about this, it just ensures me in my reply to this question.

Comment: @KubeKubow you're welcome. I agree that this is confusing yet typical for Microsoft. There is no documentation for this feature online. I found it after going through the Edge Collections window in Edge, where at the bottom I read "Powered by Bing", which was hyperlinked to [this](https://www.bing.com/saves?FORM=SVSHRD). That's how I found Bing Saves. You should check if your Edge Collections are being synced to some other account or not at all, and so are not showing up in Bing saves. The feature works perfectly for me, showing all my collection lists.

Comment: I just found that I am not able to use this feature at all. I triple checked (Linux, Android and even Windows) that my collections are being synced fine, however the `bing/saves` is partly working just on windows (it looks it is using a cache from the browser itself - not from the cloud) but definitely not on LINUX. I might wait another period and test it again, but for now this feature is not usable on Linux (and either on Windows for me).

Comment: @KubeKubow this could just be an AB testing thing, and I sympathize with your frustration. On Linux, I recommend you play around with a user-agent spoofing extension, [something like this](https://github.com/ray-lothian/UserAgent-Switcher/). Spoof your client to be on the Edge browser, and on Windows. Clear cache, log in, and try.